# Get remaining time execution of php script

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the current remaining time of an execution php script.

I tried:

```
$urls1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
$total_urls = count($urls1);
foreach ($urls1 as $url) {
  $start_time = microtime(true);
  // here I do some things
  $time_end = microtime(true);
  $execution_time = $time_end - $start_time;
  $current_urls_remaining = $total_urls - 1;
  $total_time = $current_urls_remaining * floatval($execution_time);
  $timeleft = $total_time - floatval($execution_time);
  $db->query("UPDATE sessions SET timeleft = '$timeleft'");
}
```

// the problem is that it's updated with random numbers

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
 Iteration 1 - Remaining approximate time let's say 5 second
 Iteration 2 - Remaining approximate time 4 seconds
 Iteration 3 - Remaining approximate time 3.5 seconds
 ...
```

I am pretty sure I am mistaking the formula for doing this, If anyone could help with an example would be much appreciated. I am not talking about inventing artificial intelligence just need an example on how to get the remaining time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decrement `$total_urls`, then it should work, I think.

For example:

```
$urls1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
$total_urls = count($urls1);
foreach ($urls1 as $url) {
  $start_time = microtime(true);
  // here I do some things
  $time_end = microtime(true);
  $execution_time = $time_end - $start_time;
  $current_urls_remaining = --$total_urls;
  $total_time = $current_urls_remaining * floatval($execution_time);
  $timeleft = $total_time; //former: $timeleft = $total_time - floatval($execution_time);
  $db->query("UPDATE sessions SET timeleft = '$timeleft'");
}
```

You will never get an accurate value that way, because once the execution might last 0.3s and the next time 1.2s which would lead to an approximated duration of 2.7s **first** and 9.6s **afterwards**. To avoid too heavy variation, you should apply a smoothing filter.

PS: Of course you should rename/rearrange the variable names then, because nobody would expect `$total_urls` to decrement every iteration...

EDIT:

One possibility to avoid the havy variations is, to take the average of the last 4 values as estimated duration:

```
$urls1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
$total_urls = count($urls1);
$sf_last_values = array();
foreach ($urls1 as $url) {
  $start_time = microtime(true);
  // here I do some things
  $time_end = microtime(true);

  $execution_time = $time_end - $start_time;
  $sf_last_values[] = $execution_time;
  if(count($sf_last_values) > 4)
    array_shift($sf_last_values);
  $smoothened_execution_time = array_sum($sf_last_values) / count($sf_last_values);

  $current_urls_remaining = --$total_urls;
  $total_time = $current_urls_remaining * floatval($smoothened_execution_time);
  $timeleft = $total_time; //former: $timeleft = $total_time - floatval($execution_time);
  $db->query("UPDATE sessions SET timeleft = '$timeleft'");
}
```

Comment: Almost what I want, I can see that in the end is showing 0, so good sign, but I don't like that is going from lower values to higher values, I want just to see it decrement those seconds like if the current value is bigger than the past value than show the past value. How can I do this?

Comment: @user3467855 This will **never** be possible, because you would have to predict the future. You can only *estimate* but never *know* how much time is remaining. And as your *estimation* gets more accurate over time, it may increase and decrease. Less, if you apply a smoothing filter.

Comment: So how do I do a smooth filter? I tried what you edited second time, but still values are jumping from lower to higher. I mean how do those Remaining time scripts do it in the standard way?

Comment: @user3467855 It gets smoother, as you rise the `4` in `if(count($sf_last_values) > 4)`. You also might want to exclude the first run, because most computers/algorithms/os's do the same thing faster after they did it once.

Comment: Yep true, added instead of 4, $bigger_than = ($total_urls/2) + 50/100 * $total_urls; and it runs very smooth.

Comment: @user3467855 Sry, no offense, but I had to laugh when I saw your formula, because: `$bigger_than = ($total_urls/2) + 50/100 * $total_urls;` => `$bigger_than = ($total_urls/2) + 1/2 * $total_urls` => `$bigger_than = $total_urls/2 + $total_urls/2` => `$bigger_than = $total_urls` but that is okay, it actually makes sense but you should use the short form of that formula ;)

Comment: LOL, just realized, added 80/100